# Get Response Content Length in Global.asax Application_EndRequest function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, content-length

I am adding some diagnostics logging to my ASP.NET MVC application. This happens by writing to a log file in the `Application_EndRequest()` function of the `Global.asax` file.

I want to include the content length in this logging, but when I try to access the `Response.Headers["content-length"]` value there is no header there. There is one when I check the networking tab on the developer tools:

[image: Developer Tools - Networking tab]

From what I've researched I think this means that the header isn't available at the time the `Application_EndRequest()` function of the `Global.asax` file is called. Is there any other way I can surmise the content length in this function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The HttpResponse object puts `ContentLength` into its own property and not in headers. Did you try `Response.ContentLength`?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I tried that as well, but there is no definition for a `ContentLength` property

Comment: oh, sorry, they added that for asp.net core.